# QooxDoo: Dialog contrib Error

Tags: qooxdoo

I am doing RIA application with QooXDoo, I want to use Dialog like windows to prompt & notify the user.

I have used dialog contrib from qooxdoo. But i got following error when i am trying to run

```
dialog.Dialog.warning( "I warned you!" );
```

***Error in property decorator of class dialog.Alert in method setDecorator with incoming value 'shadow-popup': Is invalid!***

I did added Dialog contrib in "config.json" file as follows.

```
    "libraries" : 
    {
      "library" :
      [
        {
          "manifest" : "../qx-contrib-Dialog-master/Manifest.json"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Can any one guess what is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution for this error.

I just removed the following line from Dialog.js file, after that all are working fine.

```
'decorator'  : "shadow-popup"
```

But shadow effect is missing.

So i did wrote a decorator named "shadow-popup" in theme file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Can you give some context?

- Which version of `qooxdoo` and `qx-contrib-Dialog` are you using?
- Which type of application are you developing (`contribution|desktop|inline|mobile|native|server|website`)?
- Do you get an error message when running `./generate.py source`?

I'm not sure what your problem is but when starting from scratch everything works for me (using `qooxdoo-2.1`, creating a `desktop` app and using the current head of the master branch from `qx-contrib-Dialog`):

```
$ cd workspace
$ wget/unzip => qooxdoo-2.1-sdk/     // I've already done that before...
$ ./qooxdoo-2.1-sdk/create-application.py -n stackoverflow
$ git clone https://github.com/cboulanger/qx-contrib-Dialog.git

file system at this moment:
  workspace/
    |-- qooxdoo-2.1-sdk/
    |   |-- application/
    |   |-- component/
    |   |-- create-application.py
    |   `-- ...
    |-- qx-contrib-Dialog/
    |   |-- Manifest.json
    |   |-- README.md
    |   |-- demo/
    |   |-- qooxdoo/
    |   `-- source/
    |-- stackoverflow/
    |   |-- Manifest.json
    |   |-- config.json
    |   |-- generate.py
    |   |-- readme.txt
    |   `-- source/ 

$ cd stackoverflow
$ vim config.json

  config.json
.-----------
| ...
| "libraries" :
| {
|  "library" :
|  [
|    {
|      "manifest" : "../qx-contrib-Dialog/Manifest.json"
|    }
|  ]
| }
| ...

$ ./generate.py source
$ vim source/class/stackoverflow/Application.js

  Application.js (adapted with reference to the demo on github [1])
.-----------
|  ...
|  // Add an event listener
|  button1.addListener("execute", function(e) {
|    // alert("Hello World!");
|    dialog.Dialog.warning( "I warned you!" );
|  });
| ...
|

$ ./generate.py source (cause the dialog classes aren't known yet)

Open app in your browser! :)
```

[1] https://github.com/cboulanger/qx-contrib-Dialog

Comment: I am using qooxdoo-2.0.1 & qx-contrib-Dialog 0.6 and its a Inline application. I did downloaded qx-contrib-Dialog to local system.
 There is no error message in "./generate.py source"